# adding data to stl container without raw loops

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I've often seen that you can replace all handwritten/raw loops with stl algorithms. Just to improve my C++ knowledge I've been trying just that.

To populate a std::vector with data I use a for loop and the loops index.

```
unsigned int buffer_size = (format.getBytesPerSecond() * playlen) / 1000;

    // pcm data stored in a 'short type' vector
    vector<short> pcm_data;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < buffer_size; ++i)
    {
        pcm_data.push_back( static_cast<short>(amplitude * sin((2 * M_PI * i * frequency) / format.SampleRate)) );
    }
```

The above code works fine, as you can see I use the for loops index 'i' for the algorithm to be correct.

How can someone replace that for loop with something from the standard?

The only functions i've seen that almost allow me to do it are std::transform and std::generate, but both of those wouldn't work because I require an index value to increment for the code.

EG:

```
generate_n(begin(pcm_data), buffer_size, [] ()
    {
        return static_cast<short>(amplitude * sin((2 * M_PI * i * frequency) / format.SampleRate)); //what is i??
    });

    transform(begin(pcm_data), end(pcm_data), begin(pcm_data) [] (???)
    {
        return static_cast<short>(amplitude * sin((2 * M_PI * i * frequency) / format.SampleRate)); //what is i??
    });
```

Or am I simply going too far into the idea of "no raw loops"?

Comment: Your initial `for` loop looks good and is readable. Since you need the item index, `generate` or the like would work by incrementing another variable (that your lambda can capture, for instance). Not sure what would be the benefit here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use a variable in the scope of your "generate_n" to declare your variable.

```
unsigned int i = 0;
generate_n(begin(pcm_data), buffer_size, [&] ()
    {
        return static_cast<short>(amplitude * sin((2 * M_PI * (i++) * frequency) / format.SampleRate)); //what is i??
    });
```

Comment: He will have to initialize `pcm_data` with the correct number of entries if he uses this as is.  He could avoid that requirement by passing `std::back_inserter( pcm_data )` as the first argument, but creating the vector with the correct number of elements is probably the better solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and it's so obvious! The other answers are great especially James K, but I only had 1 instance where I needed this loop; creating classes and such is a tad overkill for my current requirements.

Answer (score 7):

The real solution here would be to define an appropriate
iterator, something like:

```
class PcmIter : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, short>
{
    int myIndex;
    double myAmplitude;
    double myFrequency;
    short myValue;

    void calculate()
    {
        myValue = myAmplitude * std::sin( 2 * M_PI * myIndex * frequency );
    }
public:
    PcmIter( int index, amplitude = 0.0, frequency = 0.0 )
        : myIndex( index )
        , myAmplitude( amplitude )
        , myFrequency( frequency )
    {
        calculate();
    }

    bool operator==( PcmIter const& other ) const
    {
        return myIndex == other.myIndex;
    }
    bool operator!=( PcmIter const& other ) const
    {
        return myIndex != other.myIndex;
    }
    const short& operator*() const
    {
        return myValue;
    }

    PcmIter& operator++()
    {
        ++ myIndex;
        calculate();
    }

    PcmIter operator++( int )
    {
        PcmIter results( *this );
        operator++();
        return results;
    }
};
```

In practice, I suspect that you could get by with having
`operator*` return a value, which you calculate at that point,
and not having a `myValue` member.

To use:

```
std::vector<short> pcmData(
    PcmIter( 0, amplitude, frequency),
    PcmIter( buffer_size ) );
```

(The amplitude and the frequency are irrelevant for the end
iterator, since it will never be dereferenced.)

Ideally, this would be a random_access_iterator, so that the
constructor to vector will calculate the number of elements, and
pre-allocate them.  This involves implementing a lot more
functions, however.

If you're courageous, and have to do similar things a lot, you
could consider making the iterator a template, to be
instantiated over the function you're interested in.

And while I've not had a chance to play with them lately, if
you're using Boost, you might consider chaining
a `transform_iterator` and a `counting_iterator`.  It's still
a bit wordy, but the people who did the iterators at Boost did
the best they could, given the somewhat broken design of STL
iterators.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend [`counting_iterator` in Boost Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html). A pair of counting iterators provides you a range of integer. Obviously, there is no underlying container. It provides the integer "lazily". The library provides factory function `make_counting_iterator` for creating it.

`back_insert_iterator` (with factory function `back_inserter`) in Standard Library (header `iterator`) effectively calls the member `push_back` of the container.

With these ingredients, you can use `transform` with the "index".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Create a pair of counting iterators
    auto first = boost::make_counting_iterator(0);
    auto last = boost::make_counting_iterator(10);

    vector<int> vi;

    // Construct a vector of a few even number, as an example.
    transform(first, last, back_inserter(vi), [](int i){ return 2 * i; });

    // Print the result for check
    copy(vi.begin(), vi.end(), ostream_iterator<int>{cout, "  "});

    return 0;
}
```

The print-out:

```
0  2  4  6  8  10  12  14  16  18
```

Comment: Why not add a `boost::transform_iterator` which uses the counting iterator as its base?  That way, you don't even need `std::transform`: `std::vector<int> vi( first, last );` will do the trick directly.

Comment: @JamesKanze It's good idea, but not my style. Personally, I want to see there is a `transform` algorithm explicitly sitting in the code. I think iterator should stick to the job of iterating a container/lazy/logical/etc sequence, and let the algorithm do the transform. It would be good if there is some version of `transform` returning a pair of `transform_iterator`, effectively a lazy sequence of result.

Comment: Interesting.  I can see your point, although I'm not sure that it applies here.  The name `transform_iterator` seems about as explicit as `std::transform` to me.  But I agree that the fact that the vector contains a "transformation" should in some way be explicit.  (In my own response, the name of the iterator is meant to reflect the actual transformation: it creates pcm.)

Answer (score 1):

not necessarily better but a solution with stl:

```
struct generate_value {

short operator() () const {return amplitude * sin((2 * M_PI * i++ * frequency) / format.SampleRate);}

private:

unsigned i = 0;
};

generate_n(back_inserter(pcm_data), buffer_size, generate_value{});
```

Comment: While this will almost certainly work in practice, you're not actually guaranteed that all of the generated values will use the same copy of the generator object, so putting state in member variables isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Since I've had stateful functors since... forever, I'm curious to know if that's a general remark for functors or specific to `generate_n`?

Comment: @JohannGerell It's a general remark; it applies to pretty much every functional object (and predicates and such as well) that you pass to the standard library.  An implementation could theoretically make a new copy of the object each time it applies it.  (In practice, it won't; the object will be passed in by copy, but that's about it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks, it's really cool to still learn things about C++ after having used it for eons :) Just looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object and there in the "maintain state example", the state is correctly passed in the functor ctor. Guess I've been really lucky so far. Or not... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of possibilities I haven't seen mentioned yet. One would start with an iterator for a range of numbers:

```
template <class T>
class xrange_t {
    T start;
    T stop;
public:
    xrange_t(T start, T stop) : start(start), stop(stop) {}

    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T> {
        T current;
    public:
        iterator(T t) : current(t) {}
        T operator *() { return current; }
        iterator &operator++() { ++current; return *this; }
        bool operator!=(iterator const &other) const { return current != other.current; }
        bool operator==(iterator const &other) const { return current == other.current; }
    };

    iterator begin() { return iterator(start); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(stop); }
};

template <class T>
xrange_t<T> xrange(T start, T stop) {
    return xrange_t<T>(start, stop);
}
```

Then you'd use this with a ranged-for loop to do the real work:

```
#include "xrange"

for (auto i : xrange(0, buffer_size))
    pcm_data.push_back( static_cast<short>(amplitude * sin((2 * M_PI * i * frequency) / format.SampleRate)) );
```

Another possibility would be to carry out the job in a couple of steps:

```
std::vector<short> pcm_data(buffer_size);

std::iota(pcm_data.begin(), pcm_data.end(), 0);
std::transform(pcm_data.begin(), pcm_data.end(), pcm_data.begin(), 
    [](short i) { 
        return static_cast<short>(amplitude * sin((2 * M_PI * i * frequency) / format.SampleRate)));
    }
);
```

This starts by filling the array with the successive values of `i` (i.e., the inputs to the function) then transforms each of those inputs to the matching output value.

This has two potential shortcomings though:

1. If the value of `i` might exceed the value that can be stored in a `short`, it might truncate the input value during the initial storage phase. It's not clear whether your use of `int` for `i` reflects the possibility that it might have a larger magnitude, or just using `int` by default.
2. It traverses the result vector twice. If the vector is large (especially if it's too large to fit in cache) this could be substantially slower.